# How to use `ccache -s` to show hit rates for different CCACHE_DIR

Tags: c++, jenkins, devops, ccache

When I use `ccache -s`, I get like this.

```
root@iZwz98um4r4f2aucz24e1yZ:~# ccache -s
cache directory                     /root/.ccache
primary config                      /root/.ccache/ccache.conf
secondary config      (readonly)    /etc/ccache.conf
```

But when I set different environment `CCACHE_DIR` for my different C++ projects, how can I get my `CCACHE_DIR` statistics? Is there parameters can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to set the `CCACHE_DIR` (temporarily if you want) when running `ccache -s`, for instance like this:

```
CCACHE_DIR=/path/to/the/cache/dir ccache -s
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://ccache.dev/manual/4.5.1.html):

> **-d, --dir PATH**
>
> Let the command line options operate on cache directory PATH instead of the default. For example, to show statistics for a cache directory at /shared/ccache you can run ccache -d /shared/ccache -s. Using this option has the same effect as setting the environment variable CCACHE_DIR temporarily.

Available from Ccache version 4.0 onwards.